# Deezer API: Search result is empty

Tags: php, api, deezer

I've got a problem. I'm making something with the Deezer api. When I try to search with the api I'm always getting an empty result.

To test it I'm using this code:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('https://api.deezer.com/2.0/search?q=Avicii');
?>
```

When I visit the url in my browser it works fine. But when I visit the PHP-file it outputs:

```
{"data":[],"total":0}
```

I'm also getting data from a Deezer playlist and that works fine!
I searched the web for it but I've got no idea what's wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot confirm. It works fine for me. Is this your **exact** code, or do you actually paste something else into it? Try to actually paste the code you posted here in your PHP code.

Comment: It's part of something bigger but I made a PHP-file "test.php" pasted this part of the code in it but when I visit "test.php" it get {"data":[],"total":0}"

Comment: Are you querying from the US? If you're in a country where we're not live yet, you'll get empty results.

Comment: No I'm not using it in the US. But the country where I'am Deezer is live. I can get data from a Deezer playlist like I said

Comment: I'd need more details, such as where your server's hosted, etc.

Comment: I am having the same problem. From Brazil the API works fine. From my Rackspace server, in US, it does not... :-(

Comment: @Julaie I am experiencing this problem from a server hosted in Rackspace US Northern Virginia (IAD) zone

Comment: When queried from a US server, the search API returns empty results. This is regular behavior as we’re not live there.